# Keep bots and crawlers from recognizing images

Tags: image, search-engine

I want to present an image to my visitors, and I don't mind if they download it (they can always take a screenshot anyway), but I don't want this image to appear in any search results ever.

While I know that I can politely ask bots not to index my content, I don't trust them. Therefore, I want them to not recognize my image. Two ideas:

1. Create my image through e.g. PHP's image functions: `<img src="image.php">`. But I guess Google understands this.
2. Publish my image as a table, with each cell 1x1 pixels and the background color of that pixel: `<td style="width:1px;height:1px;background-color:#36ef2a"></td>`.

**Better ideas?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: If anything it's about Seach Engine Unoptimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Does this include not trusting `/robots.txt` file in your setup? Not sure if that is what you meant.

What type of images are they? If they are mostly text, and can be represented with drawings, you can try using the [HTML5 Canvas Element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) and/or [Inline SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp) to present your image.

I'm not sure if you can use background images to help your point inside the CSS.